# If x is a real number, then $x^2 ≥ 0$. The equality holds if and only if $x = 0$

Tags: number-theory

Could someone explain it to me on why the equality only holds if and only if x = 0.

Wouldn't values of the set of all real numbers apply?

Comment: The "if and only if" means that (i) if $x=0$ then $x^2=0$; (ii) if $x^2=0$ then $x=0$.  Are you asking about proving the second part?

Comment: I'm assuming you are treating $\ge$ as an "equality". In reality, $\ge$ has $2$ parts, the "equality" ($=$) and the "inequality" ($>$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment above points out I think you misunderstood the question. The set of real numbers makes the inequality true. Now, for what values of $x$ is $x^2=0$. So, if $x=0$, then $x^2=0$ no problem. Now, if $x^2=0$, then $x^2=x \cdot x = 0$. Is there any other number multiplied by itself which equals zero (explain why).

Comment: yea thought equality is referencing the '>=' not the literal definition